# What are the build.prop settings for a modern tablet?

Tags: settings, installation

I want to install a tablet-only game via the play store, and I am at the build.prop file, only I don't know what to change the device to - does anyone know what values I can put in for the ro.product.name and ro.product.model for a new-ish tablet? something along the lines of a galaxy tab s for example?

Comment: Which phone and which game you're trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T just change the model number/name. What you have to change is the DPI setting of your phone for this specific app.

For that, follow up this explanation to do so with XPosed:
http://highonandroid.com/android-apps/how-to-run-apps-in-phone-or-tablet-mode-on-any-rooted-android-smartphonetablet/

Comment: Err.. pretty sure I can change the model/name, as I have done it before to get Google wallet before it was released to non-nexus phones.. either way, I am still looking for what those two lines would be on a tablet

Comment: @user2813274 Yes, but Google play is looking for the DPI setting to look if your device is a tablet or a phone.

Comment: Dpi seems like a poor choice considering how some newer tablets have a very high resolution compared to slightly order phones

Comment: @user2813274 Note: DPI ≠ PPI